# Selenium Webdriver (Python) ActionChains not working in 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium : 3.5

Firefox : 54

Geckodriver : 0.18

I am trying to automate some browser events in python using selenium webdriver.
 Click and move_to_element are working fine in the above versions, but double_click and context_click are not working. I just realized that it's an issue with latest selenium version. Double click & right click are working in 2.53 & Firefox 46 combination, but I want to use latest versions of selenium & firefox.

Is there any workaround for Selenium Webdriver ActionChains?
Is it possible to double-click a web element using JavaScript inside my python script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post it on Selenium google groups.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/661 Looks like there's a few issues on geckodriver about this